# How do I make this script run in a loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the following script, the gameObject travels from origin to destination and then from destination to origin once. How do I run this in an infinite loop?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestSphere : MonoBehaviour
{     
    public float speed = 3;
    public Vector3 target = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 origin;

    void Start()
    {
        origin = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position == target) target = origin;
    }
}
```

Comment: which gameObject??

Comment: make a Console App and in the Main method have a while true loop where you call these 2 methods

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ the script is attached to a sphere gameObject

Comment: @apomene this is Unity specific and a `while(true)` loop would completely destroy the main thread ;)

Comment: the update will run every frame the object exists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
target = origin
```

overwrites your original `target` value and it is "forever lost".

You can go on using this but then you should do

```
if (transform.position == target)
{
    target = origin;
    origin = transform.position;
}
```

so you have the original target (== current `transform.position`) value stored for switching next time.

---

Alternatively you could do it by a simple flag:

```
private bool backToOrigin;

void Update()
{
    // if flag is true travels to origin otherwise to target
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, backToOrigin ? origin : target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    // if one of the two positions is reached invert the flag
    if (transform.position == target || transform.position == origin)
    {
        backToOrigin = !backToOrigin;
    }
}
```

---

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, backToOrigin ? origin : target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

is a one-line shorthand for writing

```
if(backToOrigin)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, origin, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
else
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Ofc!! Why did'nt I think of this! Now it works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just store the target and origin in seperate variables/fields/propertiey and take a thrid variable. This third one is used for the movement and instead of assigning the target var use your third one. create a new if clause where you test against the origin and just apply the origin to your third var. than it will switch between  target and origin